# getting this issue after deploying asp.net app to azure server 'The resource cannot be found.'

Tags: asp.net, azure

HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. What can be done to resolve this issue

Comment: What framework and URL are you using?

Comment: Hi..i got it resolved but i have got another issue on crystal report 'Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'.....i have tried many links but was not able to resolve...

Comment: I have answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71442126/how-to-resolve-following-issue-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-log4net-vers/71462858#71462858).